# Java JSON parsing exception after creating JSON in PHP on the server

Tags: java, php, json

I have this string that gets passed from the server:

```
{\"error\":\"email_in_diff_account\"}
```

It is created in PHP like this:

```
$post_data = array('error' => "email_in_diff_account");

echo json_encode($post_data);
```

But when I try to parse it like this in JAVA:

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);
```

It causes the following exception.

> org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Would anyone know how to fix this? Am I not creating the JSON correctly in php?

Comment: Please don't ever forget to post your exception/error messages. And when you do, don't bury it in a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

You are trying to parse an array but you are passing it an object, you should use http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If those backslashes are there, that would be your issue. Please post the exception though.

Comment: this is the exception: org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

First of all this code can't create json like this

```
$post_data = array('error' => "email_in_diff_account");
echo json_encode($post_data);

{\"error\":\"email_in_diff_account\"}   // your output

{"error":"email_in_diff_account"}   // actual output
```

you can validate yor JSON using this link http://jsonlint.com/

see the working example of your code  http://codepad.org/oJXj0GdI

Comment: do you mean that the PHP was supposed to create those strings without the backslashes?

Comment: PHP did not add the backslashes, this was an artifact of whatever you were using to display your string

Answer (score 1):

The correct use is:
`JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);`